# icefaces 3 form onkeydown event don't fire

Tags: javascript, icefaces-3

I am using Icefaces 3 .

I want to perform javascript function when enter key is pressed on the form.

I used this code in my previous applications (on Icefaces 1.8) and it worked fine . 
but now this is not working in Icefaces3 :

here is my code :

```
<ice:form id="queryForm" onkeydown="submitOnEnter(event);">
```

and in my header I have :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function submitOnEnter(event){
        alert("submitOnEnter");
    if( event.keyCode == 13 || evt.keyCode == 13 )
         {
    document.getElementById('queryForm:formSubmit').click();
    }
 };
 </script>
```

the javascript doesn't work when I am using keys events , but when I am using mouse events they work o.k.

how can I fix this?

Comment: try removing event as argument when you call function: submitOnEnter();. Maybe it could help

Comment: thanks. I found a solution  i canged the ice:form... to "ice:form id="queryForm" onkeydown="submitOnEnter(event);" partialSubmit="true""